# Using JS to control Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have been toying around with Bootstrap's accordion feature and learning a lot about how to use it.  However, one thing I have been having difficulty with:

I am making a web page for a classroom.  My goal is to make an accordion in which the first tab opens and the students perform a task within the tab.  When they get a correct answer, they are permitted to open the second tab, and so on.  In other words, I want to use JS or JQuery to lock subsequent tabs of the accordion and haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Hopefully my question was clear!

Comment: Your Code and/ or jsfiddle PLS

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I don't really have code of my own yet.  Thus far, I have used the generic Bootstrap code for an accordion (http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp).  I'm hoping to get a nudge in the right direction for how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This one is good option http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: My thought process so far is that instead of using:

<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>

I would use a box and then be able to use Javascript or JQuery to instantiate an event when the box is clicked.  I haven't yet figured out how to instantiate the Bootstrap collapse using Javascript, though.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  :)

My biggest challenge right now, though, is making it so that clicking on the button does not automatically open the box.  My goal is to lock the collapsible group until a certain set of parameters is met.  A good example of what I am looking for is here: http://www.scholastic.com/unexpectedmath/ratio-challenge/activity.htm?theme=baseball

Comment: In the example that I linked, you can't open the "Stairs" part of the accordion until you correctly answer the "Seats" question.

Comment: It works fine. where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how it works  :)  I didn't make the site that I linked.  I want to make a site that does what that site does.

Comment: Use jquery ui for layout, then create a form for every layout with questions, put jquery validate function to check the answer and if the answer is correct fire the code that opens second tab.

Comment: I'm going to look more deeply into the link that you gave me for JQuery Accordion widget.  Thanks again for that.  I think what I will need to do is play with the "if" statements so that it won't toggle if the right conditions aren't met.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.  I will look more into JQuery validation functions.  I haven't used JQuery very much, so I do have a lot to learn with it.

Comment: Thats rigth, create layout first and start with simple inputs, open second accordion and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out js accordion here: https://codepen.io/onlintool24/pen/LYzevEq

```js
    var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItem');
    var accHD = document.getElementsByClassName('accordionItemHeading');
    for (i = 0; i < accHD.length; i++) {
        accHD[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
    }
    function toggleItem() {
        var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
        for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
            accItem[i].className = 'accordionItem close';
        }
        if (itemClass == 'accordionItem close') {
            this.parentNode.className = 'accordionItem open';
        }
    }
```

```css
.accordionWrapper{padding:30px;background:#fff;float:left;width:80%;box-sizing:border-box;margin:10%; }
.accordionItem{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:'Open-sans',Arial,sans-serif;
}
.accordionItemHeading{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding:20px;
    background:#c2cfd826;
    color:#000;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
.close .accordionItemContent{
    height:0px;
    transition:height 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    
}
.open .accordionItemContent{
        padding: 20px;
    background-color: #7cda24;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
        padding-top: 1px;
}

.open .accordionItemHeading{
    margin:0px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #7cda24;
    color:white;
}
h2.accordionItemHeading {
    border-radius: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordionWrapper">
<div class="accordian">
<div class="accordionItem open">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem close">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionItem close">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="accordionItem close">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="accordionItem close">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="accordionItem close">
      <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">WHEN EXACTLY WILL I RECEIVE THIS PRODUCT?</h2>
      <div class="accordionItemContent">
        <p>Our products are delivered via email and available immediately after purchase! An order confirmation email with a download link will also be sent to the email provided.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```